# Dataframe groupby multiple value

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe like below:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([('bird', 'Falconiformes', 389.0),
   ...:                    ('bird', 'Psittaciformes', 24.0),
   ...:                    ('mammal', 'Carnivora', 80.2),
   ...:                    ('mammal', 'Primates', np.nan),
   ...:                    ('mammal', 'Carnivora', 58),
                           ('reptile', 'Some Animal', 30],
   ...:                    
   ...:                   columns=('class', 'order', 'max_speed'))
   ...: 

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
class    order           max_speed
bird     Falconiformes   389.0
bird     Psittaciformes  24.0
mammal   Carnivora       80.2
mammal   Primates        NaN
mammal   Carnivora       58.0
reptile  Some Animal.    30
```

How should I group the dataframe by class into two group, bird and reptile as one group and mammal on the another group? The class will only consist of bird, mammal and reptile

For normal grouping, this is my approach.

```
gb = df.groupby('class')    
for x in gb.groups:
    dff = gb.get_group(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a mapping and apply to your dataframe as a new column.

[image]